# Firefox: DOM Inspector - Highlight element like chrome/firebug

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

In Firefox when you hover over a DOM element using the inspector it's marked by a transparent box with a dashed border.

[image: Firefox DOM inspector]
<sub>(source: [mozillademos.org](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5323/inspector-no-element-selected.png))</sub>

In chrome and firebug the DOM element is highlighted, showing the content area, padding, border, and margin all in different translucent colors (Firebug also does this).

[image: Chrome DOM inspector]

Is there a `userChrome.css` tweak to add this behavior to the default Firefox DOM inspector? Or perhaps a lightweight addon that extends the inspector?

### Update:

I see there is currently an [open issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663778) for this that is already assigned and being worked on. There's even a preliminary screen shot!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if this feature only comes with Firefox 30.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector#Selecting_elements

Comment: Yep! I've been following the issue for a little over a half a year now, it was just marked as fixed a month or two ago! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this add on, it will let you colorize the DOM firefox , customize ,add many other effects

Download it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document url("chrome://browser/content/devtools/markup-view.xhtml") {

    body { background: white !important }

}
```

The above is a sample for the background only. Another css example is one below.

---

```
/* This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
 * License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
 * file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  color: hsl(0,0%,50%);
  background: black !important;
}

.text {
  color: white !important;
}

.newattr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: hsl(0,0%,90%);
}

/* Give some padding to focusable elements to match the editor input
 * that will replace them. */
span[tabindex] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 0;
}

li.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.codebox {
  padding-left: 14px;
}

.expander {
  position: absolute;
  -moz-appearance: treetwisty;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}

.expander[expanded] {
  -moz-appearance: treetwistyopen;
}

.more-nodes {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.styleinspector-propertyeditor {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}


}
```

---

Comment: I'm actually talking about the 'element inspector' that shows you the outline of the selected element in the actual webpage.

Comment: Please read our [formatting help](http://superuser.com/editing-help) and familiarize yourself with formatting code. There's a preview below  the editor that allows you to check how the post will look like.